# Detect corrupted Microsoft Access database in code-behind

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao

On my legacy application based on Microsoft Access and C#, it happens that due to lack of power, some mdb databases can be result as corrupted.
In my application, before startup, I compact the databases but I would like to "detect" if is possible, if a mdb database is corrputed or not.

I checked a the documentation of DAO engine but there's no useful method to detect corrupted database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Open  Msaccess database and check any data is loss or Msaccess itself corrupted.

Comment: There is not. If you can open the file and run a _repair_ and/or a _compact_ successfully, that will be the test.